# OR clause slowing down SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need your help about the query below which takes more than 2 min to return a result:

```
SELECT 
    p.weight, 
    o.login,
    o.date, 
    o.s_address, 
    o.s_city, 
    o.s_county, 
    o.s_state, 
    o.s_country, 
    o.s_zipcode, 
    o.phone, 
    c.categoryid, 
    c.category, 
    o.orderid, 
    p.product product_name, 
    p.productcode sku, 
    d.amount, 
    v.value emplacement, 
    ( SELECT ev.value FROM xcart_extra_field_values ev LEFT JOIN xcart_extra_fields ef ON ef.fieldid=ev.fieldid WHERE ev.productid = d.productid AND ef.field = 'a_type' LIMIT 1 ) type, 
    o.customer_notes, 
    o.membership, 
    o.s_firstname, 
    o.s_lastname, 
    o.phone, 
    d.price, 
    o.email 
FROM `xcart_orders` o 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_shipping` s ON s.shippingid=o.shippingid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_order_details` d ON d.orderid=o.orderid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_products` p ON p.productid=d.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_products_categories` pc ON pc.productid=p.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_categories` c ON c.categoryid=pc.categoryid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_field_values` v ON v.productid=p.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_fields` f ON f.fieldid=v.fieldid 
WHERE o.shippingid IN ( SELECT DISTINCT shippingid FROM `xcart_rafale_shipping` WHERE rafale='1' ) 
AND ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `xcart_order_details` d2 
    LEFT JOIN `xcart_products_categories` pc2 ON pc2.productid=d2.productid 
    WHERE d2.orderid=o.orderid 
    AND pc2.categoryid NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ac2.categoryid FROM `xcart_rafale_aggregation_categories` ac2 WHERE ac2.aggregationid='12' ) 
) = 0 
AND ( 
    ( o.date BETWEEN '1386802800' AND '1386889199' ) 
    OR (o.orderid IN ('44', '55', '66')) 
) 
AND o.orderid NOT IN ('11', '22', '33', '123', '458') 
AND o.paid = 'Y' 
AND o.status <> 'F' 
AND o.status <> 'Q' 
AND o.status <> 'I' 
AND f.field = 'emplacement' 
AND pc.main = 'Y' 
ORDER BY v.value ASC, p.productcode ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

The problem may come from the following clause

```
AND ( 
    ( o.date BETWEEN '1386802800' AND '1386889199' ) 
    OR (o.orderid IN ('44', '55', '66')) 
)
```

because the query executes faster when I remove the `OR (o.orderid IN ('44', '55', '66'))`

**There are indexes on o.date and o.orderid columns**

I used the query below inspired by reply from @Clockwork-Muse:

```
SELECT 
    p.weight, 
    o.login,
    o.date, 
    o.s_address, 
    o.s_city, 
    o.s_county, 
    o.s_state, 
    o.s_country, 
    o.s_zipcode, 
    o.phone, 
    c.categoryid, 
    c.category, 
    o.orderid, 
    p.product product_name, 
    p.productcode sku, 
    d.amount, 
    v.value emplacement, 
    ( SELECT ev.value FROM xcart_extra_field_values ev LEFT JOIN xcart_extra_fields ef ON ef.fieldid=ev.fieldid WHERE ev.productid = d.productid AND ef.field = 'a_type' LIMIT 1 ) type, 
    o.customer_notes, 
    o.membership, 
    o.s_firstname, 
    o.s_lastname, 
    o.phone, 
    d.price, 
    o.email
FROM `xcart_order_details` d
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM `xcart_orders`
            WHERE (
                orderid IN ('44', '55', '66') 
                OR (`date` >= '1386802800' AND `date` <= '1386889199')
            )
            ) o
        ON o.orderid = d.orderid
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT shippingid
            FROM `xcart_rafale_shipping`
            WHERE rafale = '1') rf
        ON rf.shippingid = o.shippingid
INNER JOIN `xcart_shipping` s ON s.shippingid=o.shippingid  
INNER JOIN `xcart_products` p ON p.productid=d.productid
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM `xcart_products_categories`
            WHERE main = 'Y') pc
        ON pc.productid=p.productid
LEFT JOIN `xcart_categories` c ON c.categoryid=pc.categoryid
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_field_values` v ON v.productid=p.productid  
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_fields` f ON f.fieldid=v.fieldid
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT d2.orderid 
    FROM `xcart_order_details` d2 
    LEFT JOIN `xcart_products_categories` pc2 ON pc2.productid=d2.productid 
    WHERE d2.orderid=o.orderid 
    AND pc2.categoryid NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ac2.categoryid FROM `xcart_rafale_aggregation_categories` ac2 WHERE ac2.aggregationid='12' ) 
) 
AND o.orderid NOT IN ('11', '22', '33', '123', '458') 
AND o.paid = 'Y'
AND o.status NOT IN ('F', 'Q', 'I')
AND f.field = 'emplacement'
```

Comment: If you remove OR it may affect the rows returned from xcart_orders, which may affect how query is constructed. Joinin two rows into million row may have different execution plan than joinin million row into million row.

Comment: Is the value of `o.date` really a varchar?  Why aren't you using a date/time/timestamp type?  If you're using a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch), why isn't it a numeric type?  Which version of MySQL?  I don't work much, but I thought I'd heard something about MySQL not being able to use multiple indices per table during query execution?  Which, given that `OR` is a divergent condition would of course effect it...

Comment: Using strings for your orderid values ('44', '55', '66') probably disables the index (assuming your orderid column is numeric). Use (44, 55, 66) instead.

Comment: removing quotes doesn't fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides any other problems your query is having, or indices it may need, it's doing more work than it needs to; here's a slightly tweaked version which *might* run faster:

```
SELECT 
    p.weight, 
    o.login,
    o.date, 
    o.s_address, 
    o.s_city, 
    o.s_county, 
    o.s_state, 
    o.s_country, 
    o.s_zipcode, 
    o.phone, 
    c.categoryid, 
    c.category, 
    o.orderid, 
    p.product product_name, 
    p.productcode sku, 
    d.amount, 
    v.value emplacement, 
    (SELECT ev.value 
     FROM xcart_extra_field_values ev 
     INNER JOIN xcart_extra_fields ef 
             ON ef.fieldid = ev.fieldid
                AND ef.field = 'a_type'  
     WHERE ev.productid = d.productid) type, 
    o.customer_notes, 
    o.membership, 
    o.s_firstname, 
    o.s_lastname, 
    o.phone, 
    d.price, 
    o.email 
FROM `xcart_orders` o
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT shippingid
            FROM `xcart_rafale_shipping`
            WHERE rafale = '1') rf
        ON rf.shippingid = o.shippingid
LEFT JOIN `xcart_shipping` s 
       ON s.shippingid = o.shippingid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_order_details` d 
       ON d.orderid = o.orderid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_products` p 
       ON p.productid = d.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_products_categories` pc 
       ON pc.productid = p.productid
          AND pc.main = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN `xcart_categories` c 
       ON c.categoryid = pc.categoryid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_field_values` v 
       ON v.productid = p.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_fields` f 
       ON f.fieldid = v.fieldid
          AND f.field = 'emplacement'  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM `xcart_products_categories` pc2
                  LEFT JOIN `xcart_rafale_aggregation_categories` ac2
                         ON ac2.categoryid = pc2.categoryid
                            AND ac2.aggregationid = '12'
                  WHERE pc2.productid = d.productid
                        AND ac2.categoryid IS NULL)
AND ((o.date >= '1386802800' AND o.date <'1386889200') 
     OR o.orderid IN ('44', '55', '66')) 
AND o.orderid NOT IN ('11', '22', '33', '123', '458') 
AND o.paid = 'Y' 
AND o.status NOT IN ('F', 'Q', 'I')        
ORDER BY v.value ASC, p.productcode ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

A couple of other things -

1. You have `LEFT JOIN`s with a condition in the `WHERE` clause - this actually turns them into `INNER JOIN`s.  I've moved the relevant conditions into the join, which will likely change your results.  If you wanted an actual `INNER JOIN`, just change/remove the word.  This is why it's best to put **ALL** conditions in a join, when possible.
2. Date/time/timestamps (even if not stored as that type) are a "measurement" - *all* measurements logically have some imprecision in the recording; to reflect this please use "lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive" (`a >= x < b`, needs to be flipped for negative values) for comparisons.  I also recommend this for integer counts, for the sake of consistency.
3. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, any use of `LIMIT` (or similar statements) returns essentially uncontrollable results.  If you want exactly one value, you **must** do one of the following - 1) use an aggregate (`MAX()`, etc), 2) write your query/structure your db such that only one value will meet the criteria, 3) provide a relevant `ORDER BY` for the use of "select position x" type constructs.  Failure to do so will cause your query to return unexpected results when you least expect it (and without throwing a warning, either).  In this case I find it extremely unlikely that there is more than one instance of a value in a EAV table (essentially, case #2).
4. Your original query contains a rather obfuscated double negative (`SELECT COUNT(*) ... = 0)`).  Unfortunately, without knowing more about the nature of your data/table schema, I can't really eliminate the double negative (although I can make it more obvious.  For the sake of future maintainers, please avoid double negatives whenever possible.  In this case, it's because of your (perhaps overly) liberal use of `LEFT`-joins - Are you sure that information *isn't required*?

Comment: @StephaneKouakou what is time ?

Comment: It took 0.2927 seconds to run but many rows are duplicated so I presume something is wrong with the clauses

Comment: Probably some of your `LEFT JOIN`s should be `INNER JOIN`s (like the ones I moved a condition on?).  Without sample data it's a little hard to tell.  Which version had this problem - my version in this answer, or the modified version in your edited question (where the subquery is still doing more work than it needs to, and I don't get the point of the subquery for `xcart_products_categories`).  What tables can you eliminate until the rows stop being duplicated?  If you want more help, you need to post sample source and result data (here or as a fiddle).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely thing to help you would be to make sure you have an index on xcart_orders.orderid if you are sure that part of the query is making it slower.

Comment: Have you tried optimizing with mySQL's explain feature? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: Give it a shot, then update your question with the results if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I tried all subquerys put in joins:

```
SELECT 
    p.weight, 
    o.login,
    o.date, 
    o.s_address, 
    o.s_city, 
    o.s_county, 
    o.s_state, 
    o.s_country, 
    o.s_zipcode, 
    o.phone, 
    c.categoryid, 
    c.category, 
    o.orderid, 
    p.product product_name, 
    p.productcode sku, 
    d.amount, 
    v.value emplacement, 
    evv.Value AS type, 
    o.customer_notes, 
    o.membership, 
    o.s_firstname, 
    o.s_lastname, 
    o.phone, 
    d.price, 
    o.email 
FROM `xcart_orders` o 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_shipping` s ON s.shippingid=o.shippingid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_order_details` d ON d.orderid=o.orderid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_products` p ON p.productid=d.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_products_categories` pc ON pc.productid=p.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_categories` c ON c.categoryid=pc.categoryid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_field_values` v ON v.productid=p.productid 
LEFT JOIN `xcart_extra_fields` f ON f.fieldid=v.fieldid 
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT shippingid 
      FROM `xcart_rafale_shipping`
      WHERE rafale='1') rs
 ON rs.shippingid = o.shippingid
JOIN (SELECT d2.orderid, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM `xcart_order_details` d2 
    LEFT JOIN `xcart_products_categories` pc2 ON pc2.productid=d2.productid 
    LEFT JOIN `xcart_rafale_aggregation_categories` ac2
      ON  ac2.aggregationid='12'
      AND ac2.categoryid = pc2.categoryid
    WHERE ac2.categoryid is null
    GROUP BY d2.orderid
) dd2
  ON dd2.orderid=o.orderid 
  AND dd2.cnt = 0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ev.productid, MAX(ev.value) as 'Value'
           FROM xcart_extra_field_values ev
           LEFT JOIN xcart_extra_fields ef ON ef.fieldid=ev.fieldid
           WHERE ef.field = 'a_type'
           GROUP BY ev.productid) evv
 ON evv.productid = d.productid
WHERE (( o.date BETWEEN '1386802800' AND '1386889199' ) 
               OR (o.orderid IN ('44', '55', '66')) 
       ) 
AND o.orderid NOT IN ('11', '22', '33', '123', '458') 
AND o.paid = 'Y' 
AND o.status NOT IN ('F', 'Q', 'I')
AND f.field = 'emplacement' 
AND pc.main = 'Y' 
ORDER BY v.value ASC, p.productcode ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Given that we don't know the data in his tables, we can't guarantee that `xcart_rafale_shipping` has no multiplicity (would be nice to know for exactly this reason, though).  You've missed a bet with the `COUNT(*)` subquery (what is the comparison causing it to actually ask?).  And EAV tables need to have only value for a given attribute, or things go bad real fast, besides the fact that `MAX(...)` might not be what he needs.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse 1. `xcart_rafale_shipping` I think join should work better than subquery in where clause, doesn't matter if there are same shippingid 2. `COUNT(*)` join should work because have `INNER JOIN` on `AND dd2.cnt = 0` 3. EVV tables `MAX` he selecting in his query just limiting `LIMIT 1` without ordering results, so he selects random `ev.value`, I'm guessing that order does not matter so selecting just `MAX`.

Comment: This query takes 97.7876 seconds to run

Comment: ...if the multiplicity of `xcart_rafale_shipping` isn't 1-to-1, he's going to be getting a lot more results than he should be, specifically because they _are_ the same `shippingId`.  2) Of course the `INNER JOIN` is likely to _work_, but I don't see why it should be any more efficient there - that subquery is doing far more work than it needs to.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse o yeah now i See that `xcart_rafale_shipping` could duplicate results, EDITED